# Where does git store information about the origin of a repository

Tags: git, pull

I have a repository that I cloned from someplace a few months back and I'd really like to know where it came from. A 'git pull' returns successfully and tells me everything is up to date, but I'd really like to know where its checking.

I've looked in the usual suspects in the .git folder, but can't see anything obvious. Anyone know where this upstream information is kept?

Comment: I was using ack-grep to search the git folder and for some reason it skipped the config folder. I'll need to work out why. Thanks though, yours and Gregs comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
git remote -v
```

This information is actually stored in the `.git/config` file.

Comment: In older git repositories it can be stored in `.git/remotes/origin` file, or even in one of `.git/branches/<branchname>` files (even older).